# Can GhostDoc be configured to keep value on a single line, leave summary on multiple?

Tags: c#, summary, optionmenu, ghostdoc

I'm looking to configure GhostDoc so that the "value" is on a single line while the "summary" is always on multiple lines.

There is an option for "Keep single line when under..." but it works on both "summary" and "value".

The behavior on methods shows this is possible. The default documentation puts "summary" on multiple lines but each "param" is on a single line.

Here's an example of what I want vs. what the default/options shows:

```
////////////       Want this:
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the description.
/// </summary>
/// <value>The description.</value>


////////////       With option checked - "Keep single line when under..."
/// <summary>Gets or sets the description.</summary>
/// <value>The description.</value>


////////////       With option unchecked - "Keep single line when under..."
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the description.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// The description.
/// </value>
```